# Как преобразовать "обводку" в контур

Tags: графика, inkscape

Всех приветствую. Я загрузил себе пример `one line drawing` (рисунок, написанный непрерывной линией, как если бы рисовали, не отрывая карандаша от бумаги) На одном сайте сконвертировал его в `svg`. Открыв в `inkspace` файл, я увидел следующую картину. [image: Сегмент]

На этом скриншоте вы можете видеть один из сегментов всего рисунка. Так как у контура есть ширина онлайн-конвертер решил обвести контур первоначального изображения. То есть точки path находятся как справа от линии так и слева.

У меня есть `python` скрипт, который аппроксимирует `path` ломаной. А из-за этой обводки ломаная сначала аппроксимирует линию, а затем ещё аппроксимирует её в обратном направлении.

Как я могу избавиться от обводки? Например, как-то оставить только точки слева от контура или только справа. (Сначала в голову пришла идея просто всю ломаную разделить пополам, однако это не сработало так как аппроксимация неравномерная)

Или для моей задачи (конвертировать `one line` изображение в `svg` с линией без этой "обводки") есть более подходящее средство, чем онлайн-конвертер?

Вариант, удалять вручную все точки, прошу не рассматривать)

Спасибо за помощь

Изначальное изображение

[image: Первоначальное изображение]

Comment: А зачем такой геморрой с двойными точками? Да и в inkscape есть все средства для [преобразования](https://m.youtube.com/results?search_query=inkscape+convert+path+to+stroke) `path` в `stroke`

Comment: Если у вас есть координаты всех точек, то вам надо сразу сгенерировать нужную прямую. Зачем для этого онлайн сервисы? Формула [b-spline](https://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/Splines/b-int.html) простая же как решение квадратного уравнения.

Comment: @DiD, спасибо большое. Ваш комментарий насчёт stroke очень мне помог. А насчёт b-spline я почитаю

Comment: Я бы даже рекомендовал перейти по ссылке внизу на содержание и мельком посмотреть все главы этой книги. Там много интерактивных примеров.